# sort mixed python list in cointaining data type order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like this  `['car', 'truck', 8, 4, 'bus', 6, 1]` and output should be `['bus', 'car', 1, 4, 'truck', 6, 8]` other words it should sort all words in alphabetical order and all integers in numerical order. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: all standart sorting operations

Comment: Why is 4 < 'truck' < 6? If you can define your sorting rule a little more formally it would be easier to help.

Comment: Why do you have it that mixed and why do you want to keep it that mixed?

Comment: It looks like strings should only appear at indices in which there was initially a string, and same for ints, but in sorted order?

Comment: so the *types* keep the same positions but the *values* are ordered?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, exactly !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Separating the values by type, then sorting each type's values, then producing the result:

```
# The input
a = ['car', 'truck', 8, 4, 'bus', 6, 1]

# Collect the values by type
d = {}
for x in a:
    d.setdefault(type(x), []).append(x)

# Sort each type
d = {k: iter(sorted(v)) for k, v in d.items()}

# The result list
result = [next(d[type(x)]) for x in a]
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['bus', 'car', 1, 4, 'truck', 6, 8]
```

Comment: I'm curious about how it will work with  negative integers

Comment: @AlicePolansky Then test it?